# How to solve this simple ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Am I making a mistake in one of these steps?

$xy' = y + 2x^3 \sin^2(\frac{y}{x})$

using $u = \frac{y}{x}$, so $y' = u'x + u$:

$u'x = 2x^2 \sin^2(u)$

$\frac{du}{\sin^2(u)} = 2x dx$

integrating

$-2\cot(u)\csc^2(u) = 2 + c$

and the solution is somehow supposed to be

$\tan(y/x) = x^2 + c$

which I have no clue how to get to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a miss while integrating. $\int 2xdx$ is $x^2+C$, not $2+C$, and $\int \frac{du}{\sin^2}=-\cot u$.

So answer will be $\cot u=-x^2+C$, and it will be $\frac yx=\cot^{-1}(-x^2+C)$, $y=-x\cot^{-1}(x^2+C)$.